# Entity Framework Core on MySql calling FromSqlInterpolated and return list of entities

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am using C# in an ASP Core project with Entity Framework Core 5.0.3, and using the Pomelo EntityFrameworkCore for MySql.

I am able to call standard SP's just fine with the below method:

```
int recordCount = await context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"call `SP_ON_MYSQL` ({param1}, {param2}");
```

The SP in question outputs a result set of the Entity that I want to capture, and when I try this:

```
var qry = await context.ENITY.FromSqlInterpolated($"call `SP_ON_MYSQL` ({param1}, {param2})").SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

I get the following error:

> *'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it.

Thank you in advance for any help that can be offered.
Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.*

I have seen examples of this working with SQL Server, so please don't mark as already answered, unless you can show me an example that is not SQL Server specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var qry = await context.ENITY
  .FromSqlInterpolated($"call `SP_ON_MYSQL` ({param1}, {param2})")
  .ToListAsync()
  .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Torvin is correct.

You need to add a `AsEnumerable()`, `ToList()` etc. call before the `SingleOrDefault()` call, if you are querying from a stored procedure.
See [Re-introduce detection for non-composable SQL in FromSql
#17558](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17558) on the official EF Core repo for more information.

Here is a fully working console program, that demonstrates the approach:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public sealed class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(
                    "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So67040870",
                    b => b.ServerVersion("8.0.21-mysql")
                          .CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.NeverAppend))
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            SetupDatabase(context);

            var iceCreamId = 1;
            var searchContacts = context.IceCreams
                .FromSqlInterpolated($"CALL `GetIceCreams`({iceCreamId})")
                .AsEnumerable() // <-- Mandatory: Use AsEnumerable(), ToList() etc. or you will get an exception.
                .SingleOrDefault();

            Trace.Assert(searchContacts != null);
            Trace.Assert(searchContacts.Name == "Vanilla");
        }

        private static void SetupDatabase(Context context)
        {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
            connection.Open();

            using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE `GetIceCreams`(`someArg` int)
BEGIN
    SELECT someArg as `IceCreamId`, 'Vanilla' as `Name`;
END";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you lauxjpn. Strange that the framework would require a ToList call first. I am seeing good results with this.